# pdf device and font family "Arial" / Or: Change font name (not font) in PDF

Tags: r, pdf, fonts, typeface

I have a problem with typefaces and PDF-Output in R. On this windows machine there is no *Helvetica* and the Font used by the device seems to be *Arial* as you can see below.
The simple problem is, that Arial is used (as I want it to be) but editing the PDF-File it says *Helvetica* is used. How can I get R to write the correct Name into the PDF-file. `pdf(...,family="Arial")` won't work, as this family is not known (grDevices version 2.15.1).

Or can I substitude this font in the PDF afterwards, creating a file with the font I want?

R-PDF-Output
[image: R Output: Arial Typeface]

Comparision from this Article:[Arial vs. Helvetica](http://ilovetypography.com/2007/10/06/arial-versus-helvetica/)
[image]

Comment: Concerning your final question: No, you cannot substitute fonts afterwards, at least not easily. Each font has its individual character widths, and as PDF is not a reflowing format, you would get something at least very unpretty if you simply switched fonts afterwards. That, BTW, also is the reason why you generally do need the fonts (or at least their respective metrics, i.e. char widths) in any process which generates PDF. That being said there are the standard 14 fonts for which most data does not need to be included in a generated PDF. Still, for proper layouting, the metrics are needed.

Comment: I think with substitution from Helvetica to Arial I will be ok with the ugliness, as they have quite similar character widths and especially as Plots don't have any running texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a new font family for use with `pdf()`. This requires you to have Adobe Font Metric files (`*.afm` files) for the fonts you wish to use. You can convert the `.tty` files to `.afm` ones or find `.afm` files for Arial on the interweb if you don't already have them.

```
Arial <- Type1Font(family = "Arial",
                   metrics = c("ArialMT.afm",
                               "arial-BoldMT.afm", 
                               "Arial-ItalicMT.afm",
                               "Arial-BoldItalicMT.afm"))
```

where the character vector `metrics` contains the paths to the relevant `.afm` files, The files should be specified in this order:

1. plain face
2. bold face
3. italic face
4. bold-italic face

The you use the `pdfFonts()` function to add a mapping to these new fonts

```
pdfFonts(Arial = Arial)
```

where `Arial` is the object produced by `Type1Font()` earlier.

The final step is to use the `family` argument in `pdf()` which refers to one of the existing families as defined by `pdfFonts()`:

```
pdf("testArial.pdf", family = "Arial")
plot(1:10, 1:10)
dev.off()
```

I haven't tried this as I don't have Arial on my system nor too many `.afm` files lying around, but I pieced this together from several sources:

1. Paul Murrell and Brian Ripley (2006) Non-standard fonts in PostScript and PDF graphics. *R News*, **6(2)**:41-47.  [PDF](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-2.pdf)
2. A [posting by David L. Carlson](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-February/303063.html) on the R mailing list from earlier this year.

An alternative depending on how your system is set-up is to a Cairo-based PDF device as that will use the functions of your system to identify and load fonts based simply on their name. See `?cairo_pdf` and then the **Cairo Fonts** section of `?X11` for details.

Answer (score 5):

Since R-3.1.0, this is much more straightforward. Now, to get an Arial font, just set `family="ArialMT"`:

```
pdf("Arial.pdf", height=0.3, width=1.45, family="ArialMT")
grid::grid.text("CGJQRSafrst1237")
dev.off()
```

Quoting from the April 2014 [R-3.1.0 release notes](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2014/000572.html):

> There is a new family, "ArialMT", for the pdf() and postscript()
>     devices.  This will only be rendered correctly on viewers which
>     have access to Monotype TrueType fonts (which are sometimes
>     requested by journals).

To ensure that the pdf will be rendered correctly wherever it's viewed, you'll need to also embed the required Arial fonts in the document. Here's one easy way to do that:

```
library(extrafont)
loadfonts()  ## Really only needed the first time you use extrafont
## Modify this to point to the corresponding Ghostscript executable on your own machine
Sys.setenv(R_GSCMD = "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.07/bin/gswin64c.exe")
embed_fonts("Arial.pdf")
```

Answer (score 2):

As it is stated in the one of the comments, base 14 fonts does'nt need to be embedded and Helvetica is one of these fonts.PDF consumers are supposed to provide replacements for such fonts and Arial (or Arial MT) is often used in place of Helvetica.

I'm not familiar with R but you seem to be able to [embed fonts afterward](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/embedFonts.html)

edit: [This question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670809/how-to-get-ghostscript-to-use-embedded-fonts-in-pdf)  explains how to embed fonts afterward with ghostscript, just be sure to have GS map Helvetica (or Arial) to the version of the font you want. Thanks to Gavin Simpson
 for having me search for that :)

Comment: As I read the Question, the OP wants to use Arial directly when the PDF is generated, not embed this font afterwards.

Comment: I read "Or can I substitude this font in the PDF afterwards, creating a file with the font I want?"  ...

Comment: Yes but embedding is not substituting - it just embeds the font so that the PDF can be viewed on a system without that font available. By substituting, the OP thought they could change the PDF to use Arial after it was created using Helvetica. I don't even think embedding works if the pdf doesn't use the font, does it?

Comment: I agree that substitution is not embedding. As I said i'm not familiar with R but the function i pointed seems to rely on Ghostscript which will in fact embed the font (i think by doing its usual PDF->PS->PDF process). GS rely on an URW set of font for the 'base 14' and even has a configurable fontmap so one could end up embedding its prefered Helvetica font.

Answer (score 1):

R by default does not embed fonts. It just specifies that a Helvetica is to be used. You're probably best off embedding fonts. There's two ways to do that, either use the `cairo_pdf` device or the [`extrafont`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/extrafont/index.html) package with the usual `pdf` device. `cairo_pdf` is a lot simpler, but the output differs in subtle ways from `pdf`.

Comment: There is also native `embedFonts()`, which uses **ghostscript** to do the embedding. This embedding will only embed the fonts used though won't it? As R has not been told to use Arial how can that font be embedded. `cairo_pdf()` is a useful solution but it will *use* as well as *embed* the stated font.

Comment: @Gavin: Not embedding fonts intended to be used is looking for trouble. I assumed OP wants to both specify to be used and embed (even though he didn't use the word), which is what both `cairo_pdf` and `extrafont` do. `extrafont` just simplifies your answer followed by embedding with ghostscript.

Comment: +1 this is useful info - anything to simplify all that messing with `.afm` files is to be appreciated.