# ps2pdf: after update to Ghostscript 9.15 fonts no longer embedded

Tags: pdf, fonts, ghostscript, postscript

I updated Ghostscript from version 9.05 to 9.15. After the update, `ps2pdf` doesn't use the correct fonts in the conversion from PostScript to PDF anymore.

The fonts in question are not from the 12 default PostScript fonts. `fc-list` lists them properly and I even made sure that the font-files actually exist.

With gs 9.05 everything worked as expected. The command I use is simply

`ps2pdf $FILE $PDF_FILE_NAME`

I tried `-dEmbedAllFonts=true` but to no help.

I use the [Generic Mapping Tools](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu) to generate my PostScript files. The PostScript file looks correct when opened with Apple Mac OS X' Preview.app:

[image: Screenshot of PostScript file opened in Apples Preview.app]

Only the gs generated PDF lacks the proper fonts:

[image: Screenshot of PDF file opened in Apples Preview.app]

System:

- Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab092.2 x86_64)
- GPL Ghostscript 9.15 (2014-09-22)
- GMT 5.2.0_r13493 [64-bit] [4 cores]

I ran out of ideas on what might cause my problem. Your ideas and input are highly appreciated.

Comment: Just a similar question not answering your one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670809/how-to-get-ghostscript-to-use-embedded-fonts-in-pdf

Answer (score 2):

Seems to have been raised as a bug at:

http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=695552

Still waiting to hear a response from the bug reporter there.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `ps2pdf` with the additional option `-sFONTPATH`:

```
ps2pdf -sFONTPATH=/path/to/your/fonts $FILE $OUTPUT
```